# Why do I get "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running"?

Tags: python, asynchronous, runtime-error, event-loop

I am running the following code that tries to get some information from https://cdn.ime.co.ir but it gives me this error:

> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

My code is:

```
import requests
import json
import asyncio
import websockets
import urllib
import random
from threading import Thread

connectionData = [{"name":"marketshub"}]

r = requests.get("https://cdn.ime.co.ir/realTimeServer/negotiate", params = {
    "clientProtocol": "2.1",
    "connectionData": json.dumps(connectionData),
})
response = r.json()

#print(f'got connection token : {response["ConnectionToken"]}')

wsParams = {
    "transport": "webSockets",
    "clientProtocol": "2.1",
    "connectionToken": response["ConnectionToken"],
    "connectionData": json.dumps(connectionData),
    "tid": random.randint(0,9)
}

websocketUri = f"wss://cdn.ime.co.ir/realTimeServer/connect?{urllib.parse.urlencode(wsParams)}"

def startReceiving(arg):
    r = requests.get("https://cdn.ime.co.ir/realTimeServer/start", params = wsParams)
    print(f'started receiving data : {r.json()}')

result = []

async def websocketConnect():
    async with websockets.connect(websocketUri) as websocket:
        print(f'started websocket')
        thread = Thread(target = startReceiving, args = (0, ))
        thread.start()
        for i in range(0,10):
            print("receiving")
            data = await websocket.recv()
            jsonData = json.loads(data)
            if ("M" in jsonData and len(jsonData["M"]) > 0 and "A" in jsonData["M"][0] and len(jsonData["M"][0]["A"]) > 0):
                items = jsonData["M"][0]["A"][0]
                if type(items) == list and len(items) > 0: 
                    result = items
                    break
        thread.join()
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocketConnect())

#print([i for i in result if i["ContractCode"] == "SAFOR99"])
```

Why do I get this error message and how can I resolve the problem?

EDIT: This is the full error message in spyder IDE .............:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.7.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/selen/auto_new.py', wdir='C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/selen')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-6b5319e4825b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/selen/auto_new.py', wdir='C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/selen')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/selen/auto_new.py", line 52, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocketConnect())

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 571, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 526, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')

RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

Comment: Show the whole error message, including full stack trace, code-formatted instead of quoted.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: I added it in the EDIT part.

Answer (score 4):

You're in an IPython kernel. Don't run this in an IPython kernel. They [changed their async handling](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/autoawait.html) a while back in a way that breaks this kind of thing; the kernel itself is running in the event loop already. (Terminal IPython works a bit differently, so this might still work in IPython in a terminal, but I'd stick with running it through Python directly.)

Answer (score 0):

Install twint using:

!pip3 install --user --upgrade    git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint

if you are using Colab. This resolved the issue or me.